# How to get percentile of each element of list of matrices

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

If I have a list of matrices with same dimensions, how can I get each element of list of matrices in R? For example, I have 4 matrices:

```
> a
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.8761453  0.2821336 -0.8541406
[2,] -0.9649200  1.7734091 -1.2058440
[3,] -0.4250063 -0.8197162 -1.3997540
> b
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.2096577 -0.5440074  0.6102016
[2,] -0.1299645 -0.8943189 -1.8042720
[3,]  1.0111488  0.2547343  0.2395172
> c
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.2853833 -0.2716714  0.2330467
[2,] -0.7963095 -1.2120779  0.6909755
[3,]  0.3479346  0.1803124 -0.7400176
> d
             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.048740842 -1.0492152 -0.6889409
[2,] -0.004154795 -0.6167335 -0.8028550
[3,] -1.111915258 -2.1586534 -0.1448612
```

The result I want is if I want the 2nd least minimum of each element.

```
> res
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.0487408 -0.5440074 -0.6889409
[2,] -0.7963095 -0.8943189 -1.2058440
[3,] -0.4250063 -0.8197162 -0.7400176
```

Comment: Can u show your expected output based on the input.  It is not clear

Comment: Added expected output. Thanks for comment!

Comment: Added solution based on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need the second minimum value, create an `array` by concatenating the `matrix`es together, specify the dimensions and use `apply` with the required `MARGIN`, `sort` the elements from smallest to largest and get the second element

```
apply(array(c(a, b, c, d), c(dim(a), 4)), c(1, 2), FUN = function(x) sort(x)[2])
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -1.0487408 -0.5440074 -0.6889409
#[2,] -0.7963095 -0.8943189 -1.2058440
#[3,] -0.4250063 -0.8197162 -0.7400176
```

NOTE: Based on the OP's post, it looks like 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' are separate `matrix` objects in the global environment

Comment: The package WGCNA provides a good function "pquantile" which can do this job quickly by using paralleling. Thanks for your great solution!